# Creating a KeyPair for a integration test against NEAR using the near-js-api

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to write an integration test to call a method on a Near Protocol contract.

I've got as far as creating the account object, and now need to set the key pair to be able to make the call.

I can see that I can get the private key value by logging in on the near-cli and getting the key from the .nearcredentials folder. But it seems like I need to encode this before setting the key in the store.

```
const keyStore = new keyStores.InMemoryKeyStore();

const config = {
    keyStore,
    networkId: "testnet",
    nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
};

const near = await connect(config);
const account = await near.account("my_account.testnet");

const keyPair = ???

await keyStore.setKey(config.networkId, "my_account.testnet", keyPair);

const result = await account.functionCall({
    contractId: "nft-example.my_account.testnet",
    methodName: "nft_metadata"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to generate the KeyPair from the private key, full code example is here, but it's basically the first line of the example using the near utils function

```
const { connect, keyStores, utils, Contract } = require("near-api-js");

const keyPair = new utils.key_pair.KeyPairEd25519(process.env.TEST_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY);

const keyStore = new keyStores.InMemoryKeyStore();
await keyStore.setKey(networkId, "my_account.testnet", keyPair);

const near = await connect({
    keyStore,
    networkId,
    nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
});

const account = await near.account("my_account.testnet");

const contract = new Contract(
    account,
    'nft-example.my_account.testnet',
    {
        viewMethods: ['nft_metadata'],
        changeMethods: []
    }
);

const result = await contract.nft_metadata();

expect(result.spec).toBe("nft-1.0.0");
```